Creating a type from an object's keys and values in TypeScript
I'm trying to create a new type based on the type of a statically defined object in TypeScript. Given the following map:
const map = {
    'hello': {a: 1, b: false},
    'world': {b: 'hello', c: null}
};

I would like to produce the following type:
type MapType = {
    type: 'hello',
    a: 1,
    b: false,
} | {
    type: 'world',
    b: 'hello',
    c: null,
}

Doing this:
type MapKeys = keyof typeof map
type MapType = {
    type: MapKeys,
} & (typeof map)[MapKeys]

produces a combinatorial type where every key of map and every value are combined which is not what I'm after. Is what I'm after even possible?

You need to distribute your type over the union of keys, possibly by using a distributive object type (as coined in ms/TS#47109), as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a suitable duplication source; if not, what am I missing?

If you add as const to const map = { /* ... */ } as const; in your code, it seems to work.

@jcalz That is indeed what I want! I actually found another solution using infer but yours is definitely simpler. Thanks!
